# Is it possible to allow swyping (swiping) but disable typing in Android?

Tags: android, swipe, typing

We are currently making an app that measures speed and accuracy in typing and swyping. For that fact, we would like to make one of the parts Swype only, so no typing allowed but Swyping is. In this case swyping would only be text input by swiping your finger over the letters in the word, as most smartphones are capable of doing. Is there a way in an Android app to allow Swyping but not regular typing?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible, for a few reasons.

To the extent that it *could* be possible, it would be keyboard-specific, as each keyboard implements type-by-swiping differently and independently (if they implement it at all).  You'd need some sort of special API in each keyboard that implements that. Even if one keyboard implemented that feature, *every* keyboard would have to implement this to disallow typing. There are also input methods that aren't swiping *or* typing, such as voice typing.

Another note: the specific keyboard you're referencing (Swype) is no longer being distributed.

You could perhaps try to infer if the user is typing or swiping by the speed at which the keys are entered, but voice typing may also run into problems there.